# Kendo Grid - Multiple footer rows

Tags: grid, kendo-ui, footer, aggregate

How can I add multiple footer rows to a single Kendo Grid?  I need these footer rows to have different totals summaries.  Adding an aggregate property to the datasource and a footerTemplate to the column only adds one footer row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a way.

Each column in the grid has a footerTemplate that can be defined with HTML.  Using divs, I was able to add mulitple "rows" to the footer row.

```
$("#mygrid").kendoGrid({
dataSource: data,
columns:[
{
  field: "Column 1",
  title: "Column 1",
  footerTemplate: "#= <div>Totals A</div><div>Totals B</div> #"
},
{
  field: "Column 2",
  title: "Column 2",
  footerTemplate: "#= <div>$1000</div><div>$700</div> #"
}
]
```